# configuring emacs keys on mac os x

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs23

I've attached an external keyboard to my laptop and I've modified my keyboard mappings such that
1. Ctrl is CAPS
2. CAPS is Ctrl

I want to continue using the right Ctrl key as Ctrl instead of CAPS. Any pointes on how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Better to be a comment for keyremap4macbook: http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my mac right now so I might get this wrong, but...

Take a look at the group of variables named like `ns-right-control-modifier`, they control how the left and right modifier keys should behave.

You might need a recent version of Emacs to get full support.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a little orthogonal to your problem, but I would sugget running emacs in iTerm 2 with `emacs -nw`

I say this because then in iTerm you have a little more control over the rebinding of the modifier keys by going to iTerm -> Preferences -> Keys. There you can remap both left and right keys.

I also suggest running emacs in the terminal because then if you use a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen` you have the ability to copy and paste from a terminal window right into your emacs buffer.